# Sharing Python code as a lambda layer using the Serverless framework

Tags: python, serverless-framework

This is a follow up question to:
[This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61158117/how-to-share-code-in-serverless-with-python-properly)

I am trying to upload some shared Python code as a lambda layer to AWS Lambda using the serverless framework.

I had followed @msc's solution (with some modifications):

### Project 1:

Step 1: Create a serverless project with the following structure:

```
./
└ serverless.yml
└ common/
    └ python/
        └ Other packages as per requirements.txt
        └ my_shared_script.py - my own package
```

Step 2: Setup my `.yml` file:

```
service: library
  provider:
    name: aws
    runtime: python3.7
    stage: dev
    region: ap-northeast-1
  layers:
    Common:
      path: common
  resources:
    Outputs:
      CommonLayerExport:
        Value:
          Ref: CommonLambdaLayer
        Export:
          Name: CommonLambdaLayer
```

Step 3: Install my requirements into the `common/python/` folder:

requirements.txt:

```
pandas==1.0.5
```

Install requirements to folder:
`pip install -r requirements.txt ./common/python/`

### Project 2

Step 1: Reference the uploaded layer as from Project 1 in my `.yml` file:

```
functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    layers:
      - arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-1:182739821739:layer:Common:1
```

Step 2: All imports now work. From my `handler.py`:

```
import pandas
import my_shared_script

def hello(event, context):
    print(my_shared_script.foo())
```

Function `foo()` runs as expected.

---

My question now is that `my_shared_script.py` is now in the same folder as all the installed Python packages (there are a lot of files and folders), which makes it hard to find and maintain my own modules / scripts.

```
./
└ serverless.yml
└ common/
    └ python/
        └ Other packages as per requirements.txt
    └ lib/
        └ my_shared_script.py - my own package
```

It makes sense for me to put my own scripts in a separate folder `/lib` and install all other requirements to the `/python` folder.

However, if I use the above folder structure, the code fails.

I have put this at the top of my `handler.py` in Project 2, hoping that the script would be able to find my code in `/lib`.

```
import os
import sys

CWD = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(CWD, "../lib")))
```

I am struggling to understand Python pathing / folder structure in this serverless framework ... Hopefully some expert can share their solution, thank you.

Comment: Do you use `virtualenv` and `serverless-python-requirements`?(https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-python-requirements) Why do you install your requirements into `common/python` folder?

Comment: I figured if you could import common.py by placing it into common/python without messing with sys path, you could just pip install all libraries into the same common/python folder. Now after uploading it as a layer, i can just reference that layer in my function and import common just works, as well as any other libraries that i installed in same folder common/python

Comment: @yongsheng I'm struggling with the same problem. The more clean approach was using symbolic links.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import pandas
import sys
try:
    sys.path.index('/opt/lib')
except ValueError:
    sys.path.append('/opt/lib')
import my_shared_script

def hello(event, context):
    print(my_shared_script.foo())
```

Comment: No offense but this looks like a hack :|

Comment: I don't like this method, but after hours of looking for a solution is the only thing that worked for me using the serverless framework